# Making a script file to run *.exe file

Tags: c++

I have a small c++ program that write to standard out and I need to make script to run it so it will write to file and to standard out at the same time.

The script I got is:   *myProgram > out.txt* and it is working and when I run
myProgram directly it write to standard out.  How can I get both at the same time.

I am working on Windows.

Comment: Why is this c++ tagged? which OS?

Comment: "shell" is an odd retag. This looks like a Windows question, what with the *.exe in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For unix/linux you want to `tee` your output to the file and the output will be sent to `stdout` as well:

```
 myProgram | tee out.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

On recent Windows (Windows 7 or later), the easiest way should be to use the powershell, which has a [`Tee-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849937.aspx) cmdlet for this:

```
powershell -command "myprogram | Tee-Object out.txt"
```

For less recent Windows, take a loot at [wintee](https://code.google.com/p/wintee/), or download and install powershell from [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419.aspx).